# Selecting between 60V source and 1uV measurement

Tags: transistors, triac, instrumentation-amplifier

My goal is to perturb a sample with a 250us pulse of 100mA at 60V, then on the same probes measure the response over time in microvolts. The pulses will be repeating at about 100Hz, so most of the time measuring. The response and pulse will be AC, or +/- compared to resting state. Switching time should be 10us or less.

How can I protect my instrumentation amplifier from the 60V pulses, wouldn't using limiting diodes also limit the pulse to my sample? I'd prefer a switch or multiplexer like solution so I can use the same electronics for multiple probe pairs. Would triacs and the like result in a voltage drop, negating my uvolt measurements? Or does someone know of a component for this. A relay would have the range for this, but not practical for the switching frequency. Any other options?

Comment: `Any other options?` ... this is not answerable because you did not say what you are trying to do ... it appears at first glance that you are subjecting a 600 Ω possibly resistive load to a pulse train, but it is unclear why the load should be responding to the pulses

Comment: Define actual load reactive impedance and then use high impedance INA with series R and clamp diodes

Comment: Tezz, can you provide an example curve? This should include the initial \$250\:\mu\text{s}\$ pulse width and voltage height, followed by when you start your ADC sampling, plus your ADC sample rate and duration following the onset of the pulse. And this appears to be a "stimulus/response" problem from your description. So I don't imagine you starting sampling until after the trailing edge of the stimulus (when the stimulus is removed.) There's little information about DC content of the response. And it would help to know what that looks like. Also muxing stuff at microvolt separation is tricky.

Comment: Is this an echocardiogram type test? Or a SONAR ? What is the medium ? An approx reactive Z?

Comment: At 60V you can probably use a MOSFET to provide isolation. Switch it off, wait the switching time (probably about 30 us). apply pulse, switch on, start measuring. ON resistance should be well below 1 ohm : choose a relatively small, low current FET not a 100A monster, to keep the device capacitance down.

Answer (score 0):

Generically, some series impedance (could be just a resistor) and actively **shunt** the input to the amplifier with an analog switch, preferably in a way that keeps the output from railing (which should not be too difficult with an instrumentation amplifier since the feedback path does not involve the inputs).

To get microvolt-level error the switch shouldn't leak too much and your amplifier should not have too much bias current relative to the added resistance.  You may well have to use silicon diodes to reduce the maximum voltage the switch sees to a volt or two. That will not unduly affect your signal if it is less than 100mV or so.

If you have trouble getting the desired attenuation in one stage, try two stages with half the series resistance in front of each.

The switch capacitance and series resistance will reduce your bandwidth, but I'm guessing that probably won't be a problem.

Something like this is used for EM measurements in geophysical instrumentation.